# Basic Python conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this condition in my program:

```
if vals[k]==vals[i] and i!=k:
```

The code following the if statement gets skipped over when vals[k]==1, vals[i]==1, i==2, and k==0 when I expected those values to pass the conditions. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my understanding of Python syntax?

This is for an assignment so I don't want to include too much code in case I get accused of cheating, but here's a little more:

```
for k in range(i-i%4,i+4-i%4):
    print vals[i]
    print vals[k]
    print i
    print k
    if vals[k]==vals[i] and i!=k: 
        isMatch = True
        print 'rowmatch'
        break
```

(ignore the print statements, they're just clumsy aids to debugging)

And here's a copy of part of what the debugger returned:

[image: Sample debugger output]

[edit] Russell Borogove was right and I was comparing ints to strings. Feel pretty dumb now, thanks for your help!

Comment: Works for me. I think we need more context; something may be going on in the background that you haven't realized.

Comment: Are you sure about `vals[k]==1, vals[i]==1, i==2, and k==0`?

Comment: I removed some indentation of the code so it's a bit more readable and embedded the image. For future reference, images aren't really that useful for displaying this kind of information - so next time - please feel free to copy and paste the debugger output as a code block - that way - if someone wants to copy/paste it etc..., they can do so. Glad you found your answer though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line right before the `if` and get back to us:

```
print "vals[k] = %s vals[i] = %s i = %s k = %s"%(vals[k],vals[i],i,k)
```

Perhaps you have an incompatible mix of types in `vals`. Try:

```
for val in vals:
    print "%s %s"%(val.__class__,val)
```

Comment: It returned vals[k] = 1 vals[i] = 1 i = 2 k = 0. Maybe I'm misinterpreting the debugger, but it does seem to skip back up to the beginning of the for loop.

Comment: My best guess is that you have a mix of integers and strings in `vals`. `'1' == 1` is `False`.

Comment: Instead of ``__class__`` it's better to either use ``type()`` or even simpler, use ``repr()``.

Comment: Or instead of explicitly calling `repr()`, do `print "%r"%(val)`.